# URL validation in text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I validate the url in a text input if the user accidentally write on the text input before clicking submit?

Comment: A proper URL validation is a complex regex. Use the `<input type="url" >` or `URL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code, this will work for you

```
    function urlLocate() {
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    var regexp = /^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:(?!(?:10|127)(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!(?:169\.254|192\.168)(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]-*)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/\S*)?$/;
    if (url != "") {
        if (!regexp.test(url)) {
            alert("Please enter valid url.");
        } else {
            window.location.assign(url);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Please upload an image.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this function for Url validation.

```
function isUrlValid(userInput) {
    var res = userInput.match(/(http(s)?:\/\/.)?(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g);
    if(res == null)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this function for validating url

```
function ValidURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\/\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\d]([a-z\d-]*[a-z\d])*)\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\:\d+)?(\/[-a-z\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\?[;&a-z\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\#[-a-z\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locater
  if(!pattern.test(str)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid URL.");
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: do i put ValidURL(str) in html?

Comment: You could use a button with an onclick attribute that calls the function

Answer (score 0):

Use `form` and `<input type="url">` to validate it. The form can only be submitted with the valid value(s).

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('valid URL');
});
```

```html
<form>
  Input a URL: <input type="url" required><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @NoobTW and @Azer to use `<input type="url"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url

Examples without any JS:

Demand a URL prefix but you can make one up yourself. Both http:// and bonk:// will be accepted as valid url prefixes.

```
<form>
    <input type="url" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Now!">
</form>
```

URL validation by demanding that all url's start with either http:// or https://

```
<form>
    <input type="url" pattern="https?://.+" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Now!">
</form>
```

Require https:

```
<form>
    <input type="url" pattern="https://.+" required />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Now!">
</form>
```

https://html5-tutorial.net/form-validation/validating-urls/

With simple error message:

```
<form>
    <input type="url" pattern="https://.+" required title="Requires https://" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Now!">
</form>
```

[image]

[image]

If you wish to replace Default HTML5 Validation Message you can do it like this:

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145#Replacing%20the%20Default%20HTML5%20Validation%20Message

Answer (score -1):

### type="url"

You can give the input `type="url"` to give it a simple validation as mentioned above.

```
<input type="url" required>
```

*Please note that you should also give it the required attribute if a valid URL is required to submit the form.*

### *pattern* attribute

You can also give the input the `pattern` attribute if you want to add your own custom validation. The pattern attribute takes a regex pattern as it's value and will match it to the value of the input at validation. If you use a pattern attribute to do your own custom validation, you don't need to use the "url" input type. A simple text input will work as well.

```
<input type="text" pattern=".*\.[a-z]{2,}$" required>
```

The above is an overly simplified regex pattern that will only recognize very plain urls (like example.com) and should not be used for any serious validation. But you can change the pattern to any one of the patterns used in functions suggested in other answers, or some other pattern that fit your needs.

### Both combined

```
<input type="url" pattern="https?:\/\/*" required>
```

The above is a simple example of a url input where a pattern attribute has been applied to make the validation a little bit stricter. This way the value of the input has to pass both the standard validation of a url input field, but it also has to pass the regex pattern to be validated. In the above example, the url has to begin with either *http://* or *https://* to pass validation.